# eOS and macOS Big Sur dual boot

Tags: macbook, macintosh, apple

I wanted to dual boot elementary and macOS Big Sur but kept running into issues with out dated tutorials. After a bit of poking around, I was able to figure it out and have it posted on medium if anyone else needs it

https://taurealis.medium.com/how-to-dual-boot-elementary-os-and-macos-big-sur-and-make-uninstalling-easy-a7b9d3b0e59c

Comment: Thank you! Just wanna let you know ubiquity has an option to skip grub installation.. should be #ubiquity -b.